# Place items in specific slots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to place items in certain slots in a players inventory and I know you can testfor an item in a specific slot:

`/testfor @a[r=10] {Inventory[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"}]}` This is actually a command I used in 1.8

Instead of the testfor to test for the item in a slot, place the item in a slot, using a command like the *give* command to place the item in the specific slot:

```
/give @a[r=10] {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:leather_helmet"}]}
```

Can I do this in Minecraft 1.9?

Comment: Maybe `/replaceitem`, although I could have sworn that it, like `/entitydata` didn't work on players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, using **replaceitem**:

```
/replaceitem entity @a[r=10] slot.armor.head minecraft:leather_helmet 1 0 {}
```

I’ve tested this, and it seems to work. If you encounter any problems, please comment and I will look into it further. Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure)

PS. You can change it to an inventory slot with `slot.inventory.(0-26)`. For other places, see the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#replaceitem)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, you just solved a part of problem to a problem that I thought was solved. Now it is!

Comment: how would I do this for a normal inventory slot? What tag should I use?